# Is there a way to do cross domain javascript calls asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain

Note the following conditions :

1. it has to be asynchronous.
2. it shall not be through "cross origin resource sharing" and flash xhr.
3. No HTML5, or I could rather say, it should be cross-browser compatible. (IE6+, Chrome 5+, Opera, Mobile Safari, Safari, etc.)
4. Data passed to and fro shall be json.
5. I own both the domains and can control them.

Comment: I ended up using iFrames to achieve this.. 

The jsonp method and script injection doesn't work with firefox, it has different behaviour for "async" operation which I didn't want. http://hsivonen.iki.fi/script-execution/

I felt easyXDM was an overkill for my app.. But it does behave as advertised, so accepting it..

Comment: easyXDM isn't overkill for anything - it can be used for creating auto-resizing iframes as well as complex API's. It's up to you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [easyXDM](http://easyxdm.net) - it does all of the above and is what Twitter, Scribd, Disqus and many others are using.

It provides Cross Domain RPC and has no known attack vectors.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [JSONP](http://www.developria.com/2009/03/what-in-the-heck-is-jsonp-and.html).

Comment: Not properly, loading new scripts causes blocking.

Comment: @David Dorward, AFAIK adding a `<script>` tag to the DOM doesn't block the execution nor it freezes the browser during the remote resource is being retrieved.

Comment: @Aaron Done properly, there's no reason why JSONP should compromise a website's security

Comment: could someone verify jsonp being async ?
I tried it by setting random sleep timings on server side, the javascript was blocking in all cases.

Comment: @Shrinath, what language are you using on the server?